# Advanced Price Date Is Not Changing

Tags: magento2.3, sales, advanced-pricing

We want to extend the sale that we had for June to the end of July, when i go to Catalogue - Product - Edit the product - advanced pricing - change the date. When we hit done and go back everything looks good, but when we click save the date go back to the old value.

Every time we try to change the date we get this error in the code:

```
[2020-07-02 13:30:26] main.INFO: SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_special_price.value_id > 0, at_special_price.value, at_special_price_default.value) AS `special_price`, `at_special_from_date`.`value` AS `special_from_date`, `at_special_to_date`.`value` AS `special_to_date`, `mc`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
```

LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `at_special_price_default` ON (`at_special_price_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_special_price_default`.`attribute_id` = '78') AND `at_special_price_default`.`store_id` = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `at_special_price` ON (`at_special_price`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_special_price`.`attribute_id` = '78') AND (`at_special_price`.`store_id` = 1)
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `at_special_from_date` ON (`at_special_from_date`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_special_from_date`.`attribute_id` = '79') AND (`at_special_from_date`.`store_id` = 0)
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `at_special_to_date` ON (`at_special_to_date`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_special_to_date`.`attribute_id` = '80') AND (`at_special_to_date`.`store_id` = 0)
LEFT JOIN `mailchimp_sync_ecommerce` AS `mc` ON mc.type = 'PRO' AND mc.related_id = e.entity_id AND mc.mailchimp_sync_modified = 0  AND  mc.mailchimp_store_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' and mc.mailchimp_sync_delta < (IF(at_special_from_date.value_id > 0, at_special_from_date.value, at_special_from_date_default.value)) WHERE (IF(at_special_price.value_id > 0, at_special_price.value, at_special_price_default.value) > 0) AND (((((at_special_from_date.value <= '2020-07-02 23:59:59') OR (at_special_from_date.value IS null))))) AND (((((at_special_to_date.value >= '2020-07-02 00:00:00') OR (at_special_to_date.value IS null))))) AND (mc.mailchimp_sync_delta is not null) [] []
[2020-07-02 13:30:26] main.CRITICAL: API Key Invalid for Api Call: https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ecommerce/stores - Your API key may be invalid, or you've attempted to access the wrong datacenter. [] []

I could see there was 2 API keys on Mailchimp but when try to change the API, the same thing happens the old value goes back and do not save the value.

Anyone knows why this is happening? Someone mentioned a database reset, but not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated